# Getting all ids/values in a form in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetifys v-form component to create a form.  Inside the form there are tons of v-text-fields and v-checkbox components that get dynamically created and assigned ids.  I would like to be able to print out all ids/values (to the console as a proof of concept), but I don't see any documentation on how to do it.

Ex:

```
<v-form v-model="foo" ref="bar">
 <v-text-field :id="dynamicallyGenerated" class="baz"/>
 <v-text-field :id="anotherDynamicallyGenerated" class="baz"/>
 <v-checkbox :id="yetAnotherDynamicallyGenerated" class="baz"/>
</v-form>

...
const elements = this.$refs.bar.$el;

// And somehow I would like to get an array of all the form elements that have
// the class called "baz" then do something like this with it
someArray.forEach((entry) ==> {
  console.log(entry.id, entry.value);
});
```

I tried using `this.$refs.bar.$el.querySelectorAll(".baz");` however it returns tons of nested-divs (due to how vuetify builds components) and looks like a pain to troll though. I'm wondering if querySelectorAll is what I should be using or is there something more straightforward.

Comment: I think what you're doing looks right and probably how I would do it... are the nested divs causing issues? If so could you throw together a fiddle to show the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought. I just needed to do

```
this.$refs.bar.$el.querySelectorAll(".baz input")
```